# Solve $f(x) =f'(x) f''(x)$

Tags: derivatives

$$f(x) =f'(x) f''(x)$$ Find the polynomial function $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, with $\deg(f) =n$. I have found that the degree is $3$ but just replacing gives me that $f(x) =\frac{x^3}{18}$

Comment: That is the correct answer.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1452333/42969.